# Proof of when is $A=X^TX$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we have an $n\times m$ matrix $X$. What are the specific properties that $X$ must have so that $A=X^TX$ invertible?

I know that when the rows and columns are independent, then matrix $A$ (which is square) would be invertible and would have a non-zero determinant. However, what confuses me is, what sort of conditions must we have on each row of $X$ such that $A$ would be invertible.

It would be very nice to have a solution of the form:

1. when $n > m$ then $X$ must have...
2. when $n < m$ then $X$ must have...
3. when $n = m$ then $X$ must have...

I think in the 3rd case we just need $X$ to be invertible but I was unsure of the other two cases.

Comment: If $n=m$, it is enough to check that $\det(X) \not=0$

Comment: I am specifically interested when $n \neq m$

Comment: Hint: What happens if $X$ has full row rank?

Comment: full row rank means when all the rows of X have a pivot?

Comment: Consider $X$ as a linear operator and look what happens to the rank of the basis $(v_1,...,v_n)$ when $X$ maps it to $R^m$ and then $X^T$ maps it back to $R^n$.

Comment: @Nitish when it has a full row rank does it mean it has all independent rows, right?

Comment: Closely related questions: [If $A^TA$ is invertible, then $A$ has linearly independent column vectors](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1181271/72968) and conversely [Why is $A^TA$ invertible if $A$ has independent columns?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1840801/72968). For a statistical application, see [What is an example of perfect multicollinearity?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/221902/22228).

Comment: $X^T X$ is invertible if and only if the columns of $X$ are linearly independent.  A necessary condition for that is that $X$ must have at least as many rows as columns. $\qquad$

Comment: This question is crucially missing any hypothesis about the field over which matrices are considered. The case of complex matrices is very different from the case of real matrices, and fields of nonzero characteristic are quite different again.

Answer (score 35):

Precisely when the rank of $X$ is $m$ (which forces $n\geq m$).

The key observation is that for $v\in\mathbb R^m$, $Xv=0$ if and only if $X^TXv=0$. For the non-trivial implication, if $X^TXv=0$, then $v^TX^TXv=0$, that is $(Xv)^TXv=0$, which implies that $Xv=0$.

If the rank of $X$ is $m$, this means that $X$ is one-to-one when acting on $\mathbb R^m$. So by the observation, $X^TX$ is one-to-one, which makes it invertible (as it is square).

Conversely, if the rank of $X$ is less than $m$, there exists $v\in\mathbb R^m$ with $Xv=0$. Then $X^TXv=0$, and $X^TX$ cannot be invertible.

Comment: Which is a different way of saying that $X$ has a left inverse. Actually, if $X^TX$ is invertible, then $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is a left inverse of $X$ and is exactly the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $X$.

Comment: Wouldn't the proof need to change if the matrices are complex? Then $(Xv)^T(Xv)=0$ does not imply $Xv =0$.

Comment: Yes, properly one needs to use the adjoint and not the transpose. But usually a question that is only tagged "linear algebra" and doesn't clarify it, is considering the real case.

Answer (score 6):

It is true if and only if:

$m\le n$ and Rank$\,(X)=m$.

Assume that $m\le n$ and Rank$\,(X)=m$, and let $X^TXu=0$, for some $u\in\mathbb R^m$. We need to show that $u=0$. 
We have also that
$$
0=(X^TXu,u)=(Xu,Xu),
$$
and thus $Xu=0$. But as Rank$\,(X)=m$, this implies that $u=0$. (Otherwise, the columns of $X$ would be linearly dependent, and hence its rank less than $m$.)

Assume that $X^TX\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}$ is invertible. Then $m=$Rank$\,(X^TX)\le$Rank$\,(X)\le \min\{m,n\}$. Thus $\min\{m,n\}=m$, Rank$\,(X)=m$, and $m\le n$.

Comment: why do we need to show u = 0? I am a little confused on your notation for $0 = (XTXu, u) = (Xu , Xu)$

Comment: It is really $0=(X^T X u, u) = (Xu, Xu)$. Just a typo

Comment: Correct. I fixed it.

Comment: Wouldn't the proof need to change if the matrices are complex? Then $(Xv)^T(Xv)=0$ does not imply $Xv =0$.