# Show $X^TX$ is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Suppose that the first column of $X \in R^{N \times (p+1)}$ is full of $1$s.
Show that in the following cases, there exists no inverse matrices for $X^TX$.
(a). $N < p+1$
(b). $N \ge p+1$ and two columns of $X$ are the same.

So far, I know 1. for a matrix to be invertible, it has to be a square matrix.
2.$A^{-1}A = I = AA^{-1}$ for an invertible matrix. 
I do not understand the statement "the first column is full of $1$" How should this information be used to solve the problem? 
Could someone explain the idea?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1181271/ , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1840801

Comment: Not sure what the first column has to do with anything. If $N < p + 1$ or $X$ has two identical columns then it has a non-trivial null space. Then if $Xv = 0$ we have $X^TXv = 0$ so  $X^TX$ cannot be invertible.