# Proving change of basis matrix from $\mathcal B$ to $\mathcal B'$ is $\mathbf P$=$(\mathbf Y^T \mathbf Y)^{-1}\mathbf Y^T\mathbf X$

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

If $\mathcal B=${${x_1,x_2,...,x_n}$} and $\mathcal B'=${${y_1,y_2,...,y_n}$} are bases for an $n$-dimensional subspace of $\mathcal V \subset R^m$.

Say I let $X_{mxn}$ and $Y_{mxn}$ be the matrices whose columns are the vectors $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B'$ respectively.

How would I go about proving that the change of basis matrix from $\mathcal B$ to $\mathcal B'$ is $\mathbf P$=$(\mathbf Y^T \mathbf Y)^{-1}\mathbf Y^T\mathbf X$?

If I'm not mistaken, I would first have to show that $\mathbf Y^T \mathbf Y$ is indeed invertible?  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [$A^TA$ is invertible if A has independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840801/why-is-ata-invertible-if-a-has-independent-columns) columns, then for $v\in\mathcal V$ we have $$v=Yy=Xx\implies Y^TYy=Y^TXx\implies y=(Y^TY)^{-1}Y^TXx$$

Comment: And in this case the columns have to be independent because $A$'s columns are bases?  But, why is $Yy=Xx$?

Comment: @MarissaB Yes of course!

Comment: Just another thought, but would there be another particular outcome of $P$ when $m=n$?