# Why is $\sum_i^n \mathbf{x_i}\mathbf{x_i}'$ positive definite?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

Let $\mathbf{x_i}=[ x_{i1}, x_{i2}, x_{i3} ]'$. Why can we say that $\sum_i^n \mathbf{x_i}\mathbf{x_i}'$ is positive definite?

Comment: Take $n$ to be finite.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $n$ is not the size of the space; each vector has 3 entries.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sure. What if $n = 1$? In that case, how could the matrix be positive definite?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1840801/339790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct proof that your matrix is positive semidefinite is as follows: for any $v$, 
$$
v^T \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T \right)v = \sum_{i=1}^n (v^Tx_i)(x_i^Tv) = 
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^Tv)^2 \geq 0.
$$
Note also that this matrix is symmetric.  Your matrix will be positive definite if and only if the vectors $x_i$ span $\Bbb R^3$, which is to say that the matrix 
$$
X = \pmatrix{x_1 & x_2 &\cdots & x_n}
$$
has full row-rank.  To see this, note that we can only have $x_i^Tv = 0$ for all $x_i$ if $v$ lies in the orthogonal complement of the span of the $x_i$.