# Find rank of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, linear-regression

If $X$ is a $N \times D$ matrix with $(D\gg N)$ with $\operatorname{rank}(X) = N$, what is $\operatorname{rank}(X^T \cdot X)$ where $X^T$ is the transpose matrix of $X$?

I am little new to linear algebra and I am not having any approach, I faced this problem in other context(linear regression).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/is-the-rank-of-a-matrix-the-same-of-its-transpose-if-yes-how-can-i-prove-it

Comment: Welcome to MSE. When asking questions, people will respond more positively if you: list your efforts and thoughts and type up your question using MathJax instead of linking images. Please consider editing your question.

Comment: @Stockfish The post you linked isn't obviously relevant, and there definitely are posts on MSE about the rank of $X^TX$

Comment: @illa In general, $X^TX$ and $X$ will have the same rank

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oh, will look for proof. If you have any link handy, please share.

Comment: @illa [This is the closest](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1840801/81360) I was able to find

Comment: @illa There is also [this wikipedia subsection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Third_proof)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rank of $X^TX$ is the same as the rank of $X$, assuming real matrices.

Why? Suppose $Xv=0$. Then also $X^TXv=0$. Conversely, if $X^TXv=0$, then also $v^TX^TXv=0$, that is, $(Xv)^T(Xv)=0$; therefore $Xv=0$.

We have proved that the two matrices have the same null space. But, by the rank-nullity theorem,
\begin{align}
N&=\operatorname{rank}X+\operatorname{nullity}X \\
N&=\operatorname{rank}X^TX+\operatorname{nullity}X^TX
\end{align}
and equality of the ranks follows.