# Proof that $AA^T$ is invertible if $A$ has independent rows

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, transpose

While looking for the answer for my question I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840801/why-is-ata-invertible-if-a-has-independent-columns?rq=1) post. It may be a silly idea, but if $A^{t}$ has independent rows can I just transpose it and get $A$ with independent columns and proceed as is shown in the linked solution? Or it is not working this way?

Comment: Yes, your approach is fine.

Comment: Thank you for such a fast answer wow!

Comment: Perfectly good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is $m\times n$ and that $AA^T$ is not invertible. Then there exists $v\ne0$ (an $m\times1$ column vector) such that
$$
AA^Tv=0
$$
This implies $v^TAA^Tv=0$, hence $(A^Tv)(A^Tv)=0$, so $A^Tv=0$. Thus $v^TA=0$ and therefore $A$ doesn't have linearly independent rows.

Answer (score 0):

For every matrix $A$ with  independent rows, we have $det A \neq 0$ also $det A= det A^t$so both $A$ and $A^t$ are invertible. Then $AA^t$ is invertible if and only if $A$ is.

Comment: The matrix $A$ is not supposed to be square.

Comment: You are right $A$  is not supposed to be square.